# Ruby not respecting # encoding specification

Tags: ruby, encoding

Given the following script (it must be in its own file):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# encoding: binary

s = "\xe1\xe7\xe6\x07\x00\x01\x00"
puts s.encoding
```

The output of this is "UTF-8". Why isn't it binary (ASCII-8BIT)?

Answer (score 2):

Because the `# encoding: binary` must be on the line immediately following the `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. Alternatively, if there is no `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` line, it must then be on the first line of the file.

When the blank line is removed (i.e. the encoding specification is on the second line):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: binary

s = "\xe1\xe7\xe6\x07\x00\x01\x00"
puts s.encoding
```

...the output is "ASCII-8BIT".

Here is a link to the Ruby documentation regarding magic comments such as encoding (thanks to Stefan who mentioned this in a comment):

https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/comments_rdoc.html#label-Magic+Comments

Comment: You might want to add a link to the docs for [Magic comments](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/comments_rdoc.html#label-Magic+Comments)

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of it. It's very helpful and I have added it.